# How to rotate the text of a wx.StaticText?

Tags: python, wxpython

I want to write a Static Text with an upside down ^
How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches.

1) If you actually want to do the rotation, you can do it by drawing the text to a wx.GraphicsContext and then rotation it there, write this to a bitmap, and display that.

2) It might be easier to find the right unicode symbol.  Having spent way too much of my time lately looking at unicode symbols, I can suggest  02C7, 032C, 2228, 2304, 1D5B, 1D65.  Note, though, that not all of these will be present in all fonts.

As far as I know, wx.StaticText doesn't rotate text.

Answer (score 0):

You can either find the right unicode symbol or just use "v"